# wxPython : How to change alignment StaticText after SetLabelText

Tags: python, wxpython, wxformbuilder

If you create a frame through wxpython and change the contents of the staticText, the alignment will be initialized.
How can I solve this problem?
I want to align it again.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide a small working example of what you have and explain what it is that you wish to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dynamically set window alignment flags you have to

1. Get the wx.Sizer
2. Find the wx.SizerItem
3. Set the wx.SizerItem flags via `SetFlag`
4. call `Sizer.Layout()`

Here's a simple example:

```py
import wx
import traceback


def run():
    app = wx.App()
    # create the test frame
    frame = wx.Frame(None, title="test frame", size=(500, 500))

    # create a simple boxsizer
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
    # create the object that we'll be dynamically adjusting
    st = wx.StaticText(frame, label="Click me")
    st.SetFont(wx.Font(30, 74, 90, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, True, "Arial Rounded"))
    # align the text to the middle initially
    sizer.Add(st, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
    frame.SetSizer(sizer)

    # bind to an arbitrary event
    st.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, on_click)
    # do the initial layout and show the frame
    frame.Layout()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


def on_click(event):
    event.Skip()
    # retrieving the static text object
    st = event.GetEventObject()  # type: wx.StaticText
    # get the sizer that contains this object
    sizer = st.GetContainingSizer()  # type: wx.BoxSizer
    # find the sizer item
    # the sizer item holds the alignment information and tells
    # the sizer how to display this object
    sizer_item = sizer.GetItem(st)  # type: wx.SizerItem
    # alternate between aligning at the top & bottom
    if sizer_item.GetFlag() & wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM:
        print("Setting alignment to top")
        sizer_item.SetFlag(wx.ALIGN_TOP)
    else:
        print("Setting alignment to bottom")
        sizer_item.SetFlag(wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)
    # call Layout to recalculate the object positions
    sizer.Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        run()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        input()
```

Comment: I got an error :AttributeError: 'StaticText' object has no attribute 'SetStyle'

Comment: @Y.Wang thanks for letting me know, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 6):

This problem is caused by the autoresize of the text control so to prevent that just add wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE to the style and it will be solved.

```
txtCtrl = wx.StaticText(parent, -1, "some label", style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER| wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE)
```

The static text does not have a method called SetStyle()